# Django: TeachersDetailView не отображает элементы из базы данных

Tags: python, django, django-model

Я создал приложение "education" в проекте "edusys", получил список преподавателей из базы данных и хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку напротив каждого из преподавателей я переходил в их профиль, где можно уже отдельно увидеть информацию из базы данных о нём (что-то типа профиля, как в соц.сетях).
Но когда я попадаю на страницу teachers_detail, у меня не отображаются вообще никакие данные из бд.

Файлы моего проекта:

**education/models.py :**

```python
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Teachers(models.Model):
    tcode = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    department_s = models.ForeignKey('Departments', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    employee_post = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    academic_degree = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    GENDER_UNIT = (
        ('m', 'Мужчина'),
        ('f', 'Женщина'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_UNIT)

    class Meta:
    ordering = ['last_name', "first_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.middle_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('this_teacher', kwargs = {'pk': self.tcode })
        return reverse("education:teachers_detail", args=[self.tcode])
```

**education/urls.py :**

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

```
app_name = 'education'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('teachers/', views.TeachersListView.as_view(), name='teachers'),
    path('teachers/<int:pk>', views.TeachersDetailView.as_view(), name='teachers_detail'),
]
```

**education/views.py :**

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Teachers
from django.views import generic

class TeachersListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Teachers
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'teachers_list' 
    template_name = 'education/teachers_list.html'


class TeachersDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teachers
```

**education/teachers_list.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container"><div class="col-12"><h1>Teachers list</h1></div></div>
<div class="container">
  
  {% if teachers_list %}
  
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          
          {% for Teachers in teachers_list %}
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="{{ Teachers.get_absolute_url }}">{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name|default_if_none:"" }}</a> ({{Teachers.department_s}})</td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td>{{ Teachers.email }}</a></td>
              <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="profile.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Профиль</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    
  {% else %}
    <p>list is empty.</p>
  {% endif %}
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

**education/teachers_detail.html :**

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ Teachers.last_name }} {{ Teachers.first_name }} {{ Teachers.middle_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>email:</strong> {{ Teachers.email }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>department:</strong> {{ Teachers.department_s }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>employee post:</strong> {{ Teachers.employee_post }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>academic dehree:</strong> {{ Teachers.academic_degree }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте во `views` `context_object_name`.

```
class TeachersDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teachers
    context_object_name = "teach"
```

и на странице с выводом

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ teach.last_name }} {{ teach.first_name }} {{ teach.middle_name }}</h1>

  <p><strong>email:</strong> {{ teach.email }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>department:</strong> {{ teach.department_s }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>employee post:</strong> {{ teach.employee_post }}</a></p>
  <p><strong>academic dehree:</strong> {{ teach.academic_degree }}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

**P.S.**

Eсли не указывать `context_object_name`, то в шаблоне надо обращаться через значение по умолчанию `object`.
Или как подсказал [@ZaArs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/231791/za-ars) <имямодели_в_нижнем_регистре> в вашем случае это (teachers)

Comment: мне кажется стоит уточнить, что не так у него  с кодом

Comment: @ZaArs вы о том что если не указать `context_object_name` то в шаблоне надо обращаться через значение по умолчанию `object`?

Comment: ну, по сути да. Он пытался получить значение из модели, которую не передавал, по умолчанию, помимо `object` , доступно значение в `<имямодели_в_нижнем_регистре>` (`teachers`).

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin  спасибо огромное за ответ, теперь всё работает!!